# Nested models with has_many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example I have in my app model User, that has_many models Post. And Post has_many Attachment. So I can do this

```
user.posts
```

and this

```
post.attachment
```

But what if I want do smth like

```
user.attachments
```

Is there any build-in solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association.  You should end up with something similar to the following structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :attachments, :through => :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
end

class Attachments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :posts
end
```

The relevant section from the above link:

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up “shortcuts” through nested has_many associations...